# How to add a personal vendor to a Symfony 2 project?

Tags: symfony

I am new with Symfony 2. I would like to add classes like libraries in my project but I dont know how.

Suppose I have 2 classes A and B.

I located them at this position : vendor/my_vendor_name/xxxx/A.php and vendor/my_vendor_name/xxxx/B.php

in each classes I defined the same namespace :

```
namespace my_vendor_name/xxxx
```

Now I would like to use those 2 classes in my bundles by calling :

```
use my_vendor_name/xxxx/A or my_vendor_name/xxxx/B
```

But It is like my namespaces do not exist (class not found)... maybe I have to declare those namespaces somewhere, to register them.

My app/autoload.php

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// intl
if (!function_exists('intl_get_error_code')) {
require_once     __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php';

$loader->add('', __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs');
```

}

```
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a deeper look at the documentation. It's well explained in the [The ClassLoader Component](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/components/class_loader.html) section.

**From the documentation,**

If the classes to autoload use namespaces, use the [registerNamespace()](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.html#registerNamespace%28%29) or [registerNamespaces()](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.html#method_registerNamespaces) methods.
For classes that follow the PEAR naming convention, use the [registerPrefix()](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.html#registerPrefix%28%29) or [registerPrefixes()](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.html#method_registerPrefix) methods.

**Note,** The documentation is [full of examples](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/components/class_loader.html) that fit your needs (Adding external classes or PHP libraries to your project)

**Also,** Take a look at the [autoload](http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) section of [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/doc/) documentation.

Comment: Thanks to you...so I just have to add in autoload.php : $loader->registerNamespace('my_vendor_name/xxxx', __DIR__.'/vendor/my_vendor_name/xxxx');

Comment: problem : it says that the method registerNamespace does not exist... it is obviously not the good loader

Comment: @mlwacosmos You should have in your autoload.php file a $loader->registerNamespaces() call that register your Sf2 dependencies, no?

If the classes you added are provided with namespaces, better is to use registerPrefixes().

Comment: registerPrefixes() does not exist either. I update My question to show my autoload.php

Comment: @mlwacosmos Ok, thanks for the update, what about using $loader->add('XXX', __DIR__.'/../vendor/XXX_PATH'); ?

Comment: @mlwacosmos [This](http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/113u8u/including_zend_1_in_symfony_21_finally_fixed_it/) may also help, How to deal with [registerPrefixes() not found issue](http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/113u8u/including_zend_1_in_symfony_21_finally_fixed_it/). Basically, it depends on your Sf2 version.

Comment: no.. class not found... still. Why dont I have access of the documentation methods ?

Comment: You could also register them in composer.json to the autoload section, if you just want them added to the composer generated autoloader.

Comment: @mlwacosmos As suggested by catchamonkey You can also register them through your composer.json as explained here > [http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading](http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

Comment: Obviously only UniversalClassLoader has access to the methods we talked about... so I changed the autoload.php file to make it look like the one in the documentation... I still have one problem : __DIR__ points to my_prject/app which is not good, I would like it to point to my_project only... result : I cannot load symfony component because it looks in app/vendor/symfony which dos not exist of course

Comment: The /.. in __DIR__ . /../vendor takes care of moving up one directory and then back down to vendor.  Your description of how you added namespaces to the class libraries is a bit scary.  It usually takes a bit more.  And it's not really necessary.  Many of the vendor libraries (Twig for example) are not namespaced.  Maybe post the first few lines of A.php

Answer (score 2):

This is not the correct way to procede.

You have, in this order:

- Create a bundle under `src/` directory
- Register your bundle into `app/AppKernel.php` file
- Create your classes under your bundle
- Use those classes wherever you want

Real example:

### Bundle Creation

Create a directory under `src/` dir. This dir wll contains all your bundles. By convention, this directory should have to be your "company" name (for our example, say it is *Foo*).

After that, create a directory for your bundle, with name of your bundle. For our example. we decide to call it *FooBundle*.

So, you'll have this directory tree: `src/Foo/FooBundle/`

Into `FooBundle/` you have to create a file that is used for bundle registration. This file is reported here:

```
<?php

namespace Foo\FooBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class FooBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

File name is `FooFooBundle.php`

### Register your bundle

Go into `app/AppKernel.php` file and add this line

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    [...]
    $bundles = array(
                   [...]
                   new Foo\FooBundle\FooFooBundle());
    [...]
```

Congratulation! Your bundle is now registered!

### Create your classes

Simply create your classes into your bundle. I suggest you to pack them into a directory like `Core` or whatever you want

### Use your classes

Suppose that you have defined a class called A, into your brand new bundle.

Use it is quite simple:

```
use Foo\FooBundle\Core\A
```

into the file you want to use it

All should work now

---

### Little Note:

A bundle inserted into src is different from a bundle inserted into vendor one only because your bundle (src one) is used by you, into your project only. A vendor bundle is someone else bundle that you use into your project. Behaviours (how to create bundle, how to register and use it) are exactly the same.

### Little Note 2:

If you have to use external library or "old" php plain classes, Ahmed answer gives you a good point of start

Comment: Thank you I am going to try... By the way I heard about a autoload.php file and a registerNameSpaces method on the loader... do u know about that ?

Comment: @mlwacosmos: yes, it's "little note2". Ahmed already wrote that, so I dind't repeat ;)